# Access Sling's embbed Jackrabbit over RMI

Tags: rmi, jackrabbit, sling

I want to connect to the embedded Jackrabbit in Spring over RMI but can't figure out how.  Is the RMI endpoint started?  If not how do I start it?

Thank you,

Marty

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/RemoteAccess should provide the relevant info.