# Why does Adobe CQ 5.5 Remote JMX from a Servlet fail?

Tags: java, adobe, osgi, jmx, aem

I'm trying to get the `HeapMemoryUsage` of the publish server from the author instance.
I attached the code of the servlet which gets called below.

In the exception you can see that we get a `NullPointerException` at Line 88 which is `JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl)`.

From Jconsole or by running it from a test class (local with main method) it functions without any problems.

The Exception:

```
29.11.2012 15:01:17.407 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1354197677403] GET /bin/cqdashboard HTTP/1.1]      org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught Throwable  java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2327)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:277)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
at com.test.cq.dashboard.servlet.DashboardTestServlet.doGet(DashboardTestServlet.java:88)
.....
```

The Code:

```
String jmxUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:43004/jmxrmi";
JMXServiceURL serviceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(jmxUrl);
JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl);
MBeanServerConnection mbeanConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
ObjectName on = new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Memory");
CompositeData cd = (CompositeData) mbeanConn.getAttribute(on, "HeapMemoryUsage");
response.getWriter().write(cd.get("used"));
// System.out.println(cd.get("used"));
```

- Do I have to import some packages in the OSGi bundle?
- Do I need to use other classes provided by adobe?
- Is it not possible to do something like that?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: If this works outside of the OSGi environment you can suspect a classloading problem - you could try running your code with the -verbose:class JVM option, both outside of and inside CQ, to see which classes are loaded when that works - it might be that your bundle doesn't have access to the sun.rmi.* classes.

Note that the NPE is at RMIConnector.java:2327, and maybe caused by something else, I'd make sure to look at the full stack trace, and maybe have a look at what's happening there, you usually have the source code of that class as part of your JVM's distribution.

Comment: That the NPE is coming from RMIConnector.java:2327 I know. But I just wrote this, if somebody was asking what was on the line 88. I will try it with the parameter and im hoping to find something. That the problem could come from the classloader is a good point.
The full stacktrace you find at: http://goo.gl/tnbJX

Comment: Debugging RMIConnector sounds like a good idea, will show you exactly what's happening.

Comment: **For everyone reading this, my answer should be before the second answer from @BertrandDelacretaz . I'm having problems with the comment field (first post).**  
I hade some time to try the different suggestions out. Unfortunately none of them worked.  
- All classes are loaded when I start it with -verbose:class  
- Tried other classloader and also running the whole thing in a separate thread didn't change anything.  
I'm now going to debug in the RMIConnector class and look what is going wrong. If I don't find anything my only hope for an answer is Adobe with a careticket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Sling's embbed Jackrabbit over RMI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961025/access-slings-embbed-jackrabbit-over-rmi)